# Rails how to simulate background processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, background-process

I am creating a simulator in rails for an upcoming product. We want to model how a device that transmits data will behave, so I need to simulate the creation of multiple objects at different times. Basically, I want a method that does this:

```
def simulate_scenario_a
 create_data_packet_a (instantly)
 create_data_packet_b (5 mins delay)
 create_data_packet_c (10 mins)
end
```

These all need to be sent to the front end api as soon as they are created but i am not sure of a suitable method to use to delay them. All my delays so far prevent the main method simulate_scenario_a from completing so they are all fired at the same time. Should i use delayed jobs gem?? Advice needed

Answer (score 0):

Consider one of [background jobs](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs) gem. I prefer [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) gem.

Using [sidekiq's API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-extensions), you can

```
def simulate_scenario_a
  DataPacket.create!(params)
  DataPacket.delay_for(5.minutes).create!(params)
  DataPacket.delay_for(10.minutes).create!(params)
end
```